# Is it possible to do programmatic build events?

Tags: c#, .net, build-events

I have a solution with several wcf service projects. When they're built, I'd like to log the current release and build info to a database. Then client applications could access the information and log a warning if they're not running on the latest builds.

Services and client apps are all internally managed and this is really just to help make sure we stay in sync from one build to the next when there are changes/additions to the services between major releases.

I know you can do command line based pre/post build events, but is it possible to do programmatic build events?

Comment: Anything is possible.  Create a program that updates the dbase, run it in the post-build event.  Having it still run 5 years from now is the real expense.

Comment: I have no idea what do you mean "programmatic build events", but I think what you are looking for is usually done outside of solution/project on [build system](http://csharp-source.net/open-source/build-systems) level as a step of build->run tests->build setup/publish->send notifications/whatsnot.

Comment: Service versioning is hell. This is where something like protobuf helps a lot, supporting back and forward compatibility.

Comment: @HansPassant Yeah thanks, I thought of that but I was just hoping there might be a hook for doing it that gave you access to some meta data about your environment.